# How to count occurrences of a character in a string in Presto?

Tags: presto, trino

I am trying to find the number of frequency of a character in a string in Presto.

like `129.11.20.0` and I wan to find number of dot `.` in this string.

just wondering if any function available

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for the same in AWS athena, which is a managed presto service. It doesn't support regexp_count, so I used the following expression instead:

```
SELECT CARDINALITY(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('1.1.1.1', '\.'))
```

Comment: Excellent, I like this one

Comment: @Codek Updated the link.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [regexp_count](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_count) function.

Comment: I don't see `regexp_count` on that link, am I missing something?

Comment: No such function in PrestoDB docs either. https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html